# Is there a way to get the collective (uptime) time a AWS instance has been running

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

If a aws instance was started yesterday for 10 hours and stopped after that ran again today for 5 hours today. In the similar way if this was done for the entire month, Is it possible to get the total (uptime) hours the instance has ran.

Has anyone implemented such a functionality in java/python or is it possible to setup cloud watch in such a way that the logs are generated.

Comment: How accurate do you need this to be? There are a lot of CloudWatch metrics that are reported on a 5-minute basis, so you could just retrieve them and calculate based on the min/max timestamps. Alternatively, you could use tags and Cost Explorer, which would give you a more accurate picture but requires more work.

Comment: Was able to get it from the logs using CloudTrail. Also the below API helped me.

https://documenter.getpostman.com/view/10394726/SzYbxHEg?version=latest#8fa06aea-a0f4-4991-89d9-b41a81da0f57